# Icon Next to the Search Orb in Android TV App

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-tv

How can I add an icon next to the search orb, just as displayed below? I'd like to display a login page when the user clicks on the icon.

[image]

Comment: Hi Burakk, are you able to find the solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can't, if you want to use the standard widgets offered by the Leanback library, such as `BrowseFragment`.

There is a way of creating your own version of the `BrowseFragment` widget, so that it is fully customizable and you can add as many buttons as you like, but it is definitely not easy to do. I've written a series of posts on this subject, which you can find here:

[Building for Android TV](https://medium.com/building-for-android-tv)

There is also a demo project that already gives you a starting point for the custom interface. The code can be found on [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/dextorer/BuildingForAndroidTV) (`episode_4` is probably what you're looking for).

Comment: Hi dextor, what is the leanback and appcompat version used by Episode_3? I getting tons of error when sync gradle using the latest version (v23)

Comment: I used, but still can't find sample for the question above (2 or more icon toolbar)

Comment: There is no sample code for that, sorry. You will have to figure out by yourself the proper way of doing it.